# How to Pitch Camera Around Origin

Tags: c++, opengl, camera, rotation, eigen

I am trying to implement a camera which orbits around the origin, where I have successfully implemented the ability to yaw using the gluLookat function. I am trying to implement pitch, but have a few issues with the outcome (pitch only works if I yaw to a certain point and then pitch).

Here is my attempt so far:

```
float distance, // radius (from origin) updated by -, + keys
      pitch,    // angle in degrees updated from W, S keys (increments of +- 10)
      yaw;      // angle in degrees updated from A, D keys (increments of +- 10)


view = lookAt(
        Eigen::Vector3f(distance * sin(toRadians(pitch)) * cos(toRadians(yaw)), distance * sin(toRadians(pitch)) * sin(toRadians(yaw)), distance * cos(toRadians(pitch))),
        Eigen::Vector3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
        Eigen::Vector3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));

proj = perspective(toRadians(90.0f), static_cast<float>(width) / height, 1.0f, 10.0f);
```

I feel like my issue is the Up vector, but I'm not sure how to update it properly(and at the same time I think its fine, as I always want the orientation of the camera to stay the same, I really just want to move the position of the camera)

**Edit:** I wanted to add that I'm calculating the position based info found here: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/SphericalCoords.aspx I'm not sure if the math discussed here directly translates over so please correct me if wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be a matter of interpretation. Your code looks correct but `pitch` might not have the meaning that you think.

When `pitch` is `0`, the camera is located at the north pole of the sphere `(0, 0, 1)`. This is a bit problematic since your up-vector and view direction become parallel and you will not get a valid transform. Then, when `pitch` increases, the camera moves south until it reaches the south pole when `pitch=PI`. Your code should work for any point that is not at the poles. You might want to swap `sin(pitch)` and `cos(pitch)` to start at the equator when `pitch=0` (and support positive and negative pitch).

Actually, I prefer to model this kind of camera more directly as a combination of matrices:

```
view = Tr(0, 0, -distance) * RotX(-pitch) * RotY(-yaw)
```

`Tr` is a translation matrix, `RotX` is a rotation about the x-axis, and `RotY` is a rotation about the y-axis. This assumes that the y-axis is up. If you want another axis to be up, you can just add an according rotation matrix. E.g., if you want the z-axis to be up, then

```
view = Tr(0, 0, -distance) * RotX(-pitch) * RotY(-yaw) * RotX(-Pi/2)
```

Comment: thank you so much. Idk why, but i was so hung up on using gluLookAt that i didnt even bother to think about just doing some simple matrix combos.